How to use graphLookup to get the leaves of a tree-like data spread over 3 documents?
I have the following MongoDB collections:
items:
  _id: ObjectId

boxes: 
  _id: ObjectId
  items: ObjectId[] 
  boxes: ObjectId[]

containers:
  _id: ObjectId
  boxes: ObjectId[]

The items can be directly contained in boxes, and boxes can contain other boxes indefinitely deep.
I am trying to write a query that finds all items, both directly and indirectly contained, within boxes that are inside containers.
By directly contained, I mean an item is in a box. Indirectly contained means an item is in a box that is itself in another box, and this can go indefinitely deep.
This is the query I have tried:
db.containers.aggregate([
  {
    $graphLookup: {
      from: "boxes",  
      startWith: "$boxes",
      connectFromField: "boxes", 
      connectToField: "_id",
      as: "allBoxes"
    }
  },
  {
   $graphLookup: {
     from: "items",
     startWith: "$allBoxes.items",
     connectFromField: "items",
     connectToField: "_id",
     as: "result"
   }
  }
])

However, this returns an empty array for the "result" field. I would appreciate if anyone could help fix this query.
[EDIT]
Here's a sample data:
db={
  "items": [
    {
      "_id": 1
    },
    {
      "_id": 2
    },
    {
      "_id": 3
    },
    {
      "_id": 4
    },
    {
      "_id": 5
    },
    {
      "_id": 6
    },
    {
      "_id": 7
    },
    {
      "_id": 8,
      name: "eighth"
    }
  ],
  "boxes": [
    {
      "_id": 1,
      "items": [
        1,
        2
      ],
      "boxes": [
        2
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": 2,
      "items": [
        3,
        4
      ],
      "boxes": [
        3
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": 3,
      "items": [],
      "boxes": [
        4
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": 4,
      "items": [
        5,
        6
      ],
      "boxes": []
    },
    {
      "_id": 5,
      "items": [],
      "boxes": [
        6
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": 6,
      items: [
        8
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": 7
    },
    {
      "_id": 8
    },
    {
      "_id": 9
    },
    {
      "_id": 10
    }
  ],
  "containers": [
    {
      "_id": 1,
      "boxes": [
        1,
        10
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": 2,
      "boxes": [
        5,
        9
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": 3
    }
  ]
}


This assumes you are storing child _id in the parent's array field. (i.e. if box A contains Box B, Box A's boxes field contains "B". The same applies to containers, boxes)
I think you just need use 1 $graphLookup to recursively lookup the  boxes collection. Then, iterate through the lookup result with $reduce to get all items.
db.containers.aggregate([
  {
    "$graphLookup": {
      "from": "boxes",
      "startWith": "$boxes",
      "connectFromField": "boxes",
      "connectToField": "_id",
      "as": "insideBoxes"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "allItems": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$insideBoxes",
          "initialValue": [],
          "in": {
            "$setUnion": [
              "$$value",
              "$$this.items"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])

Mongo Playground

The query does not return the expected result. $graphLookup stage seems to be irrelevant to the result produced by the query, since the result doesn't change if you remove that stage, aside from that, the "reduce" part of the query takes $containedBoxes as input and works on "containedBoxes.items" which has nothing to do with "insideBoxes".

@Gandalf can you [edit] your question to provide sample documents and expected output?

@Gandalf updated the example with a revised sample document set and the code.

tnx, I updated the question with sample data.

I had to use $lookup instead of the second $graphLookup:
[
  {
    $graphLookup: {
      from: "boxes",
      startWith: "$boxes",
      connectFromField: "boxes",
      connectToField: "_id",
      as: "allBoxes"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$allBoxes"
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$allBoxes.items"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "item": "$allBoxes.items"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": null,
      "containedItemIds": {
        $addToSet: "$item"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "items",
      localField: "containedItemIds",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "contentItems"
    }
  }
]

Following is the result of the query for the provided data sample:
[
  {
    "_id": null,
    "containedItemIds": [
      2,
      5,
      3,
      8,
      1,
      4,
      6
    ],
    "contentItems": [
      {
        "_id": 1
      },
      {
        "_id": 2
      },
      {
        "_id": 3
      },
      {
        "_id": 4
      },
      {
        "_id": 5
      },
      {
        "_id": 6
      },
      {
        "_id": 8,
        "name": "eighth"
      }
    ]
  }
]

